# Can't recover Passphrase after encrypting home folder after Ubuntu installation

Tags: command-line, encryption, decryption

I'm quite new in Ubuntu. I've tried encrypting my home folder after installation following this link:

http://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/

However, when I try to to recover the passphrase using ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase on my home folder [nothing is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loSQW.png). However when I check my home folder I can see that there is an .ecryptfs folder,so I guess that means that it is encrypted?

Anyone knows how I can recover my Passphrase and check that my home directory is effectively encrypted? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted, I jsut have to input my password at the "Passphrase:" pront.